# How to restore iMac with Time Machine?

Tags: imac, restore

I'm trying to restore all my content. On boot I press & hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd> .
This takes me to the Internet Recovery option, yet I want to restore from my Time Machine backup.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the drive is completely empty & doesn't even have a recovery partition, then the Mac will automatically go to Internet Recovery if you hold  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>  at boot.

To prevent this, hold the  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  key at the chimes & choose your Time Machine volume to boot from. You should then find the option to Restore from Time Machine Backup.